# Reinstall Node.js

Tags: node.js

What's the best way to reinstall node.js?

Answer (score 2):

If you've already installed node, then add a a `make uninstall` in there too as the first step.  So `make uninstall; make clean; make; make install;` should do it.  Note that this has to be run from the source directory for the nodejs version you currently have installed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to reinstall you might as well allow for multiple versions, so I would highly recommend [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm)

Answer (score 0):

```
make clean

make

make install
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you pulled and built from source, you can follow the above examples. If you installed Node though apt-get, you can try something like this:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove nodejs
```

or

```
$ sudo apt-get --purge remove nodejs
```